# Is there a better framework than netty for sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, netty

Like the tittles say i need to know it!
I see that netty is pretty good on perfomace but want to know if it the best right now.
Regards,

Comment: Apache MINA is one alternative.

Comment: *Best* in terms of what?

Comment: I'll elaborate Tomasz's comment ... You could help us by explaining more about exactly what you are looking for.  What's the application?  Just in general?

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using [Apache-Mina](http://mina.apache.org/) as a widely used alternative.
We use it for example at [oVirt](http://www.ovirt.org) open source project to establish SSH connections between a virtualization manager Java EE application, 
 and hosts running virtual machines , during a process of Host Registration, and to validate connectiity (via ssh attempt ) to the host. 
In addition, 
 I worked in the past with [JBoss-Remoting](http://www.jboss.org/jbossremoting), 
 which would give you an abstraction over TCP-based protocols (such as RMI, HTTP and so on). 
I used it to build a communication layer from a management application for video processing, 
 and a stanalone J2SE application responsible for fetching video content for processing. 
I am sure there are more options, It really depends on your needs.