# Non-Web application server "framework"

Tags: java

We will be developing a server-side linux service using Java.

Does anybody have experience of a framework or an "application server" for this purpose?

Application server not in the common sense, this has nothing to do with web, http or the like. It's a server application listening on a socket, processing some stuff and then answer to it. It will be a custom protocol. So the usual suspects like Glassfish, Tomcat, Jetty, etc. aren't really what I need.

**Edit**: I'm looking for features like startup handling, automatic service recovery, and may be database connection

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What should "startup handling, automatic service recovery" roughly do?

Comment: A search for [java socket framework](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+socket+framework) led me to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423564/is-there-a-better-framework-than-netty-for-sockets) which mentions [Apache MINA](http://mina.apache.org/) and [Netty](http://netty.io/), among others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Netty for developing your tcp/ip based client-server application. It has very good documentation and arguably better performance too. If you want you could also look into Apache MINA but IMHO they do not have great documentation. QuickServer is also there if you have time to do some R&D on it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wrong - the listed usual suspects (well, Tomcat not) are in my opinion perfect fit. Shortly, what you need is an application server with Java EE 6 Full profile support - I would recommend GlassFish or WildFly, or WebLogic from commercial end. The reason is simple - **JCA (Java Connector Architecture)**. It's a Java EE specification for connecting to 3rd party, or legacy, or custom developed systems. We have used it successfully for implementing communication via application specific socket based protocol, or even for Sun-RPC and Radius (from telco) protocols. There are several examples on the web, how to utilize it - with latest Java EE spec there are also few examples for socket communication finally available. But the specification itself (JCA 1.6) is very well written and after reading it you should be able to use it.

Because it is part of Java EE, the container will support all the pooling, startup, monitoring , ... Give it a try.